# Pakistani national wishes to travel somewhere that does not require a visa

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens

I am from Hyderabad, Sindh, Pakistan and very much a professional man, having ten years' experience, nowadays working with a non-governmental organization as a Head of Department.

Please guide me for travelling from my country to another country where I would not need a visa.

Comment: It's not necessary to include your full name or telephone number in your question.  If you want to make this information available to people, you can register your [account](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/31399/danish) and add any info you like to your profile page.

Comment: What is the question? 
If you don't need a visa, book a ticket, read the regulations and jump on a plane, done.

Comment: @Formagella Pakistan, IIRC, is much like India in that for its citizens, visiting almost every other country in the world requires a visa. He wants to know WHERE in the world he would not need one (a visa).

Comment: I am VtC this question as too broad. Not because there are too many answers, but too many countries to review visa requirements for.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page [Visa requirements for Pakistani citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Pakistani_citizens) has a comprehensive list of countries that Pakistani citizens can visit without a visa, or by receiving a visa on arrival.  (Reference links are included to the Timatic database, which airlines use as an authority when deciding whether travelers need a visa before boarding a flight.)  There are currently 32 such countries, most of them in the Caribbean or Africa.